# FFmpeg not honoring bitrate for different containers?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, decode, h.264, encode

I am attempting to encode a **mp4** video file into a **flv** video. Here is what I am doing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 30 /* 30 images/s */
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P /* default pix_fmt */
/**************************************************************/
/* Add an output stream. */
static AVStream *add_stream(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec **codec,
        enum AVCodecID codec_id) {
    AVCodecContext *c;
    AVStream *st;
    /* find the encoder */
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        exit(1);
    }
    st = avformat_new_stream(oc, *codec);
    if (!st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    st->id = oc->nb_streams - 1;
    c = st->codec;
    switch ((*codec)->type) {
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        //avcodec_get_context_defaults3(c, *codec);
        c->codec_id = codec_id;
        c->bit_rate = 150 * 1000; //2314000;;
        //c->rc_max_rate = 150*1000;
        //c->rc_buffer_size = 150*1000;
        /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
        c->width = 1280;
        c->height = 720;
        /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
         * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
         * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
         * identical to 1. */
        c->time_base.den = STREAM_FRAME_RATE;
        c->time_base.num = 1;
        c->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        c->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
            /* just for testing, we also add B frames */
            c->max_b_frames = 2;
        }
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
            /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
             * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
             * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
            c->mb_decision = 2;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    return st;
}
/**************************************************************/
/* video output */
static AVFrame *frame;
static AVPicture src_picture, dst_picture;
static int frame_count;
static void open_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec *codec, AVStream *st) {
    int ret;
    AVCodecContext *c = st->codec;
    /* open the codec */
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
    frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Allocate the encoded raw picture. */
    ret = avpicture_alloc(&dst_picture, c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate picture: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    /* If the output format is not YUV420P, then a temporary YUV420P
     * picture is needed too. It is then converted to the required
     * output format. */
    if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
        ret = avpicture_alloc(&src_picture, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width,
                c->height);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate temporary picture: %s\n",
                    av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    /* copy data and linesize picture pointers to frame */
    *((AVPicture *) frame) = dst_picture;
}
static void close_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st) {
    avcodec_close(st->codec);
    av_free(src_picture.data[0]);
    av_free(dst_picture.data[0]);
    av_free(frame);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    int i, videoStream;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = NULL;
    AVCodec *pCodec;
    AVFrame *pFrame;
    AVPacket packet;
    int frameFinished;

    const char *filename;
    AVOutputFormat *fmt;
    AVFormatContext *oc;
    AVStream *video_st;
    AVCodec *video_codec;
    int ret;

    // Register all formats, codecs and network
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    // Open video file
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "input_file.mp4", NULL, NULL) != 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't open file

    // Retrieve stream information
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

    // Dump information about file onto standard error
    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, "input_file.mp4", 0);

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStream = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            videoStream = i;
            break;
        }
    if (videoStream == -1)
        return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
    if (pCodec == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -1; // Codec not found
    }
    // Open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Could not open codec

    // Allocate video frame
    pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

    // setup mux
    filename = "output_file.flv";
    fmt = av_guess_format("flv", filename, NULL);
    if (fmt == NULL) {
        printf("Could not guess format.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // allocate the output media context
    oc = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (oc == NULL) {
        printf("could not allocate context.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    oc->oformat = fmt;

    // Add the video streams using the default format codecs
    // and initialize the codecs.
    video_st = NULL;
    if (fmt->video_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        video_st = add_stream(oc, &video_codec, fmt->video_codec);
    }
    // Now that all the parameters are set, we can open the
    // video codec and allocate the necessary encode buffers.
    if (video_st)
        open_video(oc, video_codec, video_st);

    /* open the output file, if needed */
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename,
                    av_err2str(ret));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // dump output format
    av_dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1);

    // Write the stream header, if any.
    ret = avformat_write_header(oc, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n",
                av_err2str(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    // Read frames, decode, and re-encode
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if (frameFinished) {

                AVFrame* newFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame(); // Initialize a new frame
                int size = avpicture_get_size(video_st->codec->pix_fmt,
                        video_st->codec->width, video_st->codec->height);
                uint8_t* picture_buf = av_malloc(size);

                avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) newFrame, picture_buf,
                        video_st->codec->pix_fmt, video_st->codec->width,
                        video_st->codec->height);

                // Copy only the frame content without any other disturbing
                av_picture_copy((AVPicture*) newFrame, (AVPicture*) pFrame,
                        video_st->codec->pix_fmt, video_st->codec->width,
                        video_st->codec->height);

                // encode the image
                AVPacket pkt;
                int got_output;
                av_init_packet(&pkt);
                pkt.data = NULL; // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
                pkt.size = 0;

                /* Setting newFrame->pts this way produces the error 'non-strictly-monotonic PTS' */
                //if(newFrame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                //newFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(newFrame->pts, video_st->time_base, video_st->codec->time_base);

                // Setting newFrame->pts this does not produce 'non-strictly-monotonic PTS'
                newFrame->pts = frame_count;

                ret = avcodec_encode_video2(video_st->codec, &pkt, newFrame, &got_output);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                    exit(1);
                }

                if (got_output) {
                    if (video_st->codec->coded_frame->key_frame)
                    pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
                    pkt.stream_index = video_st->index;

                    if (pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts,
                                video_st->codec->time_base,
                                video_st->time_base);
                    if (pkt.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts,
                                video_st->codec->time_base,
                                video_st->time_base);

                    // Write the compressed frame to the media file.
                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
                } else {
                    ret = 0;
                }
                if (ret != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n",
                            av_err2str(ret));
                    exit(1);
                }

                fprintf(stderr, "encoded frame #%d\n", frame_count);
                frame_count++;
                av_free(picture_buf);
                av_free_packet(&pkt);
            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }

    /* Write the trailer, if any. The trailer must be written before you
     * close the CodecContexts open when you wrote the header; otherwise
     * av_write_trailer() may try to use memory that was freed on
     * av_codec_close(). */
    av_write_trailer(oc);

    /* Close video encoder (codec). */
    if (video_st)
        close_video(oc, video_st);
    // Free the streams.
    for (i = 0; i < oc->nb_streams; i++) {
        av_freep(&oc->streams[i]->codec);
        av_freep(&oc->streams[i]);
    }
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        /* Close the output file. */
        avio_close(oc->pb);
    /* free the stream */
    av_free(oc);

    // Free the YUV frame holding decoded frame
    av_free(pFrame);

    // Close the decoder (codec)
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

    // Close the input video file
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the output format to an **mp4, mov, or f4v** by changing:

```
// setup mux (FLV OUTPUT)
filename = "output_file.flv";
fmt = av_guess_format("flv", filename, NULL);
if (fmt == NULL) {
    printf("Could not guess format.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

to

```
// setup mux (MP4 OUTPUT)
filename = "output_file.mp4";
fmt = av_guess_format("mp4", filename, NULL);
if (fmt == NULL) {
    printf("Could not guess format.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Then the bitrate is honored. Here is the output of running with a **mp4** output

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input_file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
  Duration: 00:04:31.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2314 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2186 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
[libx264 @ 02268b80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 02268b80] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 02268b80] 264 - core 129 r2230 1cffe9f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=12 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=12 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=150 ratetol=1.0 qco
mp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output_file.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 150 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
encoded frame #0
encoded frame #1
encoded frame #2
encoded frame #3
.
.
.
encoded frame #8142
encoded frame #8143
encoded frame #8144
encoded frame #8145
[libx264 @ 02174240] frame I:771   Avg QP:47.71  size:  2739
[libx264 @ 02174240] frame P:5083  Avg QP:50.05  size:   833
[libx264 @ 02174240] frame B:2264  Avg QP:48.16  size:    91
[libx264 @ 02174240] consecutive B-frames: 59.6%  6.4%  9.0% 24.9%
[libx264 @ 02174240] mb I  I16..4: 34.0% 65.8%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 02174240] mb P  I16..4:  6.8%  3.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  8.5%  0.4%  1.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:79.6%
[libx264 @ 02174240] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.2%  L0:23.6% L1:76.4% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 02174240] final ratefactor: 57.62
[libx264 @ 02174240] 8x8 transform intra:52.1% inter:98.5%
[libx264 @ 02174240] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 3.1% 14.0% 0.2% inter: 0.1% 0.4% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 02174240] i16 v,h,dc,p: 69% 23%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 02174240] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23%  6% 68%  1%  1%  1%  1%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 02174240] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 18% 18%  4%  4%  5%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 02174240] i8c dc,h,v,p: 98%  1%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 02174240] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.1% UV:1.2%
[libx264 @ 02174240] ref P L0: 72.4%  0.8% 19.1%  7.6%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 02174240] ref B L0: 89.8%  9.1%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 02174240] ref B L1: 96.2%  3.8%
[libx264 @ 02174240] kb/s:193.62
```

The final file size of **output_file.mp4** is about **6.5MB** and using ffplay, I notice that bitrate was honored. Of course the quality itself shows.

Here is the output of running with a **flv** output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input_file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
  Duration: 00:04:31.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2314 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2186 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
Output #0, flv, to 'output_file.flv':
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 150 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
encoded frame #0
encoded frame #1
encoded frame #2
encoded frame #3
.
.
.
encoded frame #8142
encoded frame #8143
encoded frame #8144
encoded frame #8145
```

I noticed that the bitrate is honored as long as the container is a mp4, mov, f4v, or something similar. If I try flv, wmv, or other different containers, then the bitrate is not honored. Also, the bitrate that is automatically set for wmv is different from that of flv. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I suspect it has to do with the **pts**, however, I cannot find a solution :(.

Comment: Its has nothing to do it with pts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H.264` has very good compression algorithm and can acheive very low bitrates, but the same cannot be said about other older codecs like `flv1`. Its not the container that is causing this difference. Its the videos codec, `mp4` in ffmpeg uses `h.264` by default and flv used `flv1(h.263)`. The container `flv` support `h.264` too. and if it is only the container that you are interested in, set vcodec to `h.264` or `libx264` and you will get similar results as `mp4`.

Comment: `wmv` though cannot use `h.264` , mp4 can be played by most devices/players/browsers today.

Answer (score 1):

You set the video bitrate to 150 kbits per second. 
It is too small for video in 720p resolution.

You are using different video encoders: h264 for mp4 and Sorenson (flv1) for flv. It is not surprising that with such bit rate, they can work in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! I forgot that I was passing the default format codec to the **add_stream** function. Therefore, I was using the default for flv (which as you mentioned is flv1 and h.264 for mp4, or msmpeg4v3 for wmv). The source of error in the code above was the line:

```
// Add the video streams using the default format codecs
// and initialize the codecs.
video_st = NULL;
if (fmt->video_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
    video_st = add_stream(oc, &video_codec, fmt->video_codec);
}
```

Changing that to:

```
// Add the video stream using the h.264
// codec and initialize the codec.
video_st = NULL;
video_st = add_stream(oc, &video_codec, AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```

Resolved the issue. Here is the fixed source code/output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 30 /* 30 frames/s */
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P /* default pix_fmt */
/**************************************************************/
/* video output */
static AVFrame *frame;
static AVPicture src_picture, dst_picture;
static void open_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec *codec, AVStream *st) {
    int ret;
    AVCodecContext *c = st->codec;
    /* open the codec */
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
    frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Allocate the encoded raw picture. */
    ret = avpicture_alloc(&dst_picture, c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate picture: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    /* If the output format is not YUV420P, then a temporary YUV420P
     * picture is needed too. It is then converted to the required
     * output format. */
    if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
        ret = avpicture_alloc(&src_picture, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate temporary picture: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    /* copy data and linesize picture pointers to frame */
    *((AVPicture *) frame) = dst_picture;
}
static void close_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st) {
    avcodec_close(st->codec);
    av_free(src_picture.data[0]);
    av_free(dst_picture.data[0]);
    av_free(frame);
}
/**************************************************************/
/* Add an output stream. */
static AVStream *add_stream(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec **codec, enum AVCodecID codec_id) {
    AVCodecContext *c;
    AVStream *st;
    /* find the encoder */
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n", avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        exit(1);
    }
    st = avformat_new_stream(oc, *codec);
    if (!st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    st->id = oc->nb_streams - 1;
    c = st->codec;
    switch ((*codec)->type) {
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        avcodec_get_context_defaults3(c, *codec);
        c->codec_id = codec_id;
        c->bit_rate = 150 * 1000;
        /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
        c->width = 1280;
        c->height = 720;
        /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
         * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
         * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
         * identical to 1. */
        c->time_base.den = STREAM_FRAME_RATE;
        c->time_base.num = 1;
        c->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        c->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
            /* just for testing, we also add B frames */
            c->max_b_frames = 2;
        }
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
            /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
             * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
             * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
            c->mb_decision = 2;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    return st;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Decoder local variable declaration
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    int i, videoStream;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = NULL;
    AVCodec *pCodec;
    AVFrame *pFrame;
    AVPacket packet;
    int frameFinished;

    // Encoder local variable declaration
    const char *filename;
    AVOutputFormat *fmt;
    AVFormatContext *oc;
    AVStream *video_st;
    AVCodec *video_codec;
    int ret, frame_count;

    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();

    // Open video file
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "input_file.mp4", NULL, NULL) != 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't open file

    // Retrieve stream information
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

    // Dump information about file onto standard error
    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, "input_file.mp4", 0);

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStream = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            videoStream = i;
            break;
        }
    if (videoStream == -1)
        return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
    if (pCodec == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -1; // Codec not found
    }
    // Open codec (decoder)
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Could not open codec

    // Allocate video frame
    pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

    // setup mux
    filename = "output_file.flv";
    fmt = av_guess_format("flv", filename, NULL);
    if (fmt == NULL) {
        printf("Could not guess format.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // allocate the output media context
    oc = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (oc == NULL) {
        printf("could not allocate context.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set out format context to the format ffmpeg guessed
    oc->oformat = fmt;

    // Add the video stream using the h.264
    // codec and initialize the codec.
    video_st = NULL;
    video_st = add_stream(oc, &video_codec, AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

    // Now that all the parameters are set, we can open the
    // video codec and allocate the necessary encode buffers.
    if (video_st)
        open_video(oc, video_codec, video_st);

    /* open the output file, if needed */
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename, av_err2str(ret));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // dump output format
    av_dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1);

    // Write the stream header, if any.
    ret = avformat_write_header(oc, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    // Read frames, decode, and re-encode
    frame_count = 1;
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if (frameFinished) {

                // Initialize a new frame
                AVFrame* newFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

                int size = avpicture_get_size(video_st->codec->pix_fmt, video_st->codec->width, video_st->codec->height);
                uint8_t* picture_buf = av_malloc(size);

                avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) newFrame, picture_buf, video_st->codec->pix_fmt, video_st->codec->width, video_st->codec->height);

                // Copy only the frame content without additional fields
                av_picture_copy((AVPicture*) newFrame, (AVPicture*) pFrame, video_st->codec->pix_fmt, video_st->codec->width, video_st->codec->height);

                // encode the image
                AVPacket pkt;
                int got_output;
                av_init_packet(&pkt);
                pkt.data = NULL; // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
                pkt.size = 0;

                // Set the frame's pts (this prevents the warning notice 'non-strictly-monotonic PTS')
                newFrame->pts = frame_count;

                ret = avcodec_encode_video2(video_st->codec, &pkt, newFrame, &got_output);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                    exit(1);
                }

                if (got_output) {
                    if (video_st->codec->coded_frame->key_frame)
                        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
                    pkt.stream_index = video_st->index;

                    if (pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts, video_st->codec->time_base, video_st->time_base);
                    if (pkt.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, video_st->codec->time_base, video_st->time_base);

                    // Write the compressed frame to the media file.
                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
                } else {
                    ret = 0;
                }
                if (ret != 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
                    exit(1);
                }

                fprintf(stderr, "encoded frame #%d\n", frame_count);
                frame_count++;

                // Free the YUV picture frame we copied from the
                // decoder to eliminate the additional fields
                // and other packets/frames used
                av_free(picture_buf);
                av_free_packet(&pkt);
                av_free(newFrame);
            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }

    /* Write the trailer, if any. The trailer must be written before you
     * close the CodecContexts open when you wrote the header; otherwise
     * av_write_trailer() may try to use memory that was freed on
     * av_codec_close(). */
    av_write_trailer(oc);

    /* Close the video codec (encoder) */
    if (video_st)
        close_video(oc, video_st);
    // Free the output streams.
    for (i = 0; i < oc->nb_streams; i++) {
        av_freep(&oc->streams[i]->codec);
        av_freep(&oc->streams[i]);
    }
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        /* Close the output file. */
        avio_close(oc->pb);
    /* free the output format context */
    av_free(oc);

    // Free the YUV frame populated by the decoder
    av_free(pFrame);

    // Close the video codec (decoder)
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

    // Close the input video file
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input_file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
  Duration: 00:04:31.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2314 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2186 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 19:11:10
      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.
video codec id = 28 | name = FLV (Flash Video)
[libx264 @ 021891c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 021891c0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 021891c0] 264 - core 129 r2230 1cffe9f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=12 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=12 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=150 ratetol=1.0 qco
mp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'output_file.flv':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 150 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
encoded frame #1
encoded frame #2
encoded frame #3
encoded frame #4
.
.
.
encoded frame #8143
encoded frame #8144
encoded frame #8145
encoded frame #8146
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] frame I:771   Avg QP:47.71  size:  2739
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] frame P:5083  Avg QP:50.05  size:   833
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] frame B:2264  Avg QP:48.16  size:    91
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] consecutive B-frames: 59.6%  6.4%  9.0% 24.9%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] mb I  I16..4: 34.0% 65.8%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] mb P  I16..4:  6.8%  3.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  8.5%  0.4%  1.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:79.6%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.2%  L0:23.6% L1:76.4% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] final ratefactor: 57.62
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] 8x8 transform intra:52.1% inter:98.5%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 3.1% 14.0% 0.2% inter: 0.1% 0.4% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 69% 23%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23%  6% 68%  1%  1%  1%  1%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 18% 18%  4%  4%  5%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 98%  1%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.1% UV:1.2%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] ref P L0: 72.4%  0.8% 19.1%  7.6%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] ref B L0: 89.8%  9.1%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] ref B L1: 96.2%  3.8%
[libx264 @ 02241ae0] kb/s:193.62
```

Thank you for your help!